# getting the innerHTML after finding the innerText

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a RegEx to find the part of the text I want :

```
var re = RegExp("(?:^\\W*|(" + motBefore.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")\\W+)" + motErreur.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\W+(" + motAfter.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")|\\W*$)", "g"); 
var resultMatch = document.getElementById('edth_corps').innerText.match(re);
```

Like this I can retrieve back the part of the text I need to modify with the punctuation. The trouble I get from here is to retrieve the innerHtml of this so I can get if in this part there is tag around the "motErreur".

I need to have to innerHTML because the purpose of my function is to wrap a span around the motErreur but this :

```
var reInner = resultMatch[0].replace(new RegExp("\\b" + motErreur + "\\b", "gi"), '<span id="'+nbId+'" class="erreurOrthographe" oncontextmenu="rightClickMustWork(event, this);return false">' + motErreur + '</span>');
document.getElementById('edth_corps').innerHTML = document.getElementById('edth_corps').innerHTML.replace(resultMatch, reInner);
```

does not work since between the innerText and the innerHTML it is possible to have tag already wrap around the part of text I get.

***Example :***

- Input => `this, tset, that`; result : work fine because innerHTML and innerText are the same (no tag to mess up the search)
- Input2 => `this, <em>tset</em>, that`; result : does not work since the innerText and the innerHTML are not the same (resultMatch is not the same as variable as what it is in the last replace).

I actually have no idea how to link these two thing correctly in the simplest way possible.

Configuration : javascript, compiled in quirks mode (only utility on IE, i don't care about other browser).

Comment: Bonjour à toi, i'm trying to understand what you're looking to achieve but i'm not sure, so please confirm or add information : you got something like `<p>foofoobar motErreur foobar</p>` and you're trying to only get the `motErreur` part, and surround it with a `span` tag ?

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor I extract a portion of text from a div with content editable based on the model "wordBefore-motErreur-wordAfter" then with this i can extract the corresponding portion of text with punctuation so I can replace it with the same thing but with a span around the motErreur (for application purpose). The trouble I get is that if there is already a span around motErreur (like bolr or italic one) the last replace wont work as the innerText as a match but not with is innerHTML in these kind of case.

Comment: @Teemu this only need to work on IE I don't care about portability on other browser.

Answer (score 1):

> The trouble I get is that if there is already a span around motErreur

Assuming the innerHTML you get can only have a tag around your mot erreur you could check if there's a span this way :

```
if (theInnerHtml.firstChild) {
    // It has at least one

    var yourSpan = document.createElement('span');

    // you set the innerHTML of yourSpan with the innerHTML of the child
    // Ex <p> blablabla <em>motErreur</em> blabla </p>
    // yourSpan will be "<span>motErreur</span>"
    yourSpan.innerHTML = theInnerHtml.firstChild.innerHTML;

    // you empty the innerHTML of your the child
    // It will be <p> blablabla <em></em> blabla </p>
    theInnerHTML.firstChil.innerHTML = "";

    // Then you append your span to the firstChild
    // It will be <p> blablabla <em><span>motErreur</span></em> blabla </p>
    theInnerHTML.firstChild.appendChild(yourSpan):

}
```

This therefore implies that your innerHTML will only have 1 possible child, and that this child will be wrapping your motErreur

Comment: with what you did you only try to seek if there is a tag already around the motErreur, but I catually don't mind and need to let the actual tag around the motErreur, I just need to give him another one too, but this time the one I want and kept him wrap around is strong or em tag.

Comment: Yeah that's seems more like what I am seeking to do, but how can I know "if(theInnerHtml.firstChild)", the only way I have to find this portion of text and get only the innerText is with the firstRegEx I got.

Comment: Well in my example, theInnerHtml will be the `<p>` tag, for you i guess it's the `document.getElementById('edth_corps')` right ? then `if(document.getElementById('edth_corps').firstChild)` do the code i provided, else do the regex

Comment: Well the probs is that edth_corps is a content editable with many tag inside. So you solution is applicable only if I go trought the whole DOM tree and find the node where the text returned by my RegEx is. It's one solution that I had already in mind, but it's really like getting the big gun for such a smalls task that I was thinking maybe there is a easier solution.

Comment: Well i dont have a full access to your code so it's hard to be as generic as possible while being very specific :P is there any way you could add an id or a class to the tag that will possibly surround the motErreur ?

Comment: No since it is dinamycaly construct and i'm not in charge with this parts, this is why I use Reg Ex and try to find a way to connect my two RegEx. It is the only way I have to do it without having to process all the DOM tree everytime the corrector return a "motErreur".

Comment: Well then i hope i've been usefull somehow :)

Comment: I'll keep your solution in mind if I don't manage to connect the two part of my function :).